# Object is not callable error when reassigning a string value

Tags: python, for-loop, concatenation

The following simple Python code in the second iteration gives me the error: 'str' is not callable.

```
for i in range(1,3):
  print(i)
  str1="onestring";
  str3="thirdstring";
  str=str1+str(i)+str3;
  print(str);
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

You used `str` as a variable name. Thus hiding the built-in.
Then you try to call the variable in its own definition `str(i)`.

Using the names of built-ins for variables is a bad idea, as you just saw. It's possible solely for the very advanced purpose of replacing a built-in with your own version.

You can see the following simple example at work here http://ideone.com/z70iRn

```
orig_str = str

def my_str(o):
    print("str called")
    return orig_str(o)

str = my_str

print(str(0))
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer turns out to be simple. The variable "str" is used both as a variable name and a function. Changing variable name "str" to any other name solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

please change `str` variable, because it is a built-in Python variable.